# django csrf_exempt doesnt work

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, edx

I created my class based views in my separate django app. Get requests work fine but post requests on rest client fail with 401 status and response as follows:

```
{
    detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
}
```

I already tried adding

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(ScheduleView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

to my class based view.

I also tried decorating the view in urls.py.

But it just won't work. The same error is being returned.
What am I missing here?

By the way I am working on a separate django app on edx-platform.

Comment: Can you post some more code? Why are you bypassing csrf verification instead of providing field with csrf token into form?

Comment: did you tried only @csrf_exempt before your dispatch method?

Comment: It seems like you are using Django Rest Framework? DRF disables the usual CSRF check, and when you're using `SessionAuthentication` it forces a check regardless of `@csrf_exempt`.

Comment: I am bypassing csrf verification because I cannot pass such a token for I am creating an API view

Comment: Yes I tried @csrf_exempt but got no luck

Comment: That's what I'm telling you: `@csrf_exempt` doesn't work in combination with an `APIView` from django rest framework. If you're using `SessionAuthentication`, you _need_ to provide a valid CSRF token as you can't bypass the check.